# Memory usage/ reference in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, memory, methods

I am going to ask a basic question about Java memory usage.

Imagine we have an array List and it is large enough and we don't like to use more memory. Now if I want to pass this array to another methods in this class, or other classes through their constructor or method, do I need additional memory/is there additional memory usage for this array?

If yes, could I just make this array package level, and therefore the other classes in this package could access it directly, without any memory need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no additional memory is necessary. The parameter of a function is passed by copy of the reference. It means that for any kind of object only 4 additional bytes are used.

---

If you pass an array as parameter and you **modify** it in the body of the method the changes **will be exported outside of method**.

Instead if you **reassign** the array variable, the difference **is not visible externally**.

This happens because the parameters are passed as copy of the reference and not by reference.

```
public void vsibleModification(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // This change is visible outside of method because I change 
        // the content of a, not the reference
        a[i] = a[i] + 1;  
    }
}

public void nonVisibleModification(int[] a) {
    // Non visible modification because a is reassigned to a new value (reference modification)
    a = new int[2];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But if I change the array in the goal method/class , the original array will stay the same. doesn't it mean additional memory usage?

Comment: Thanks, for my need, the goal methods or classes do not need to change the variable, only reading is enough. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: You can pass it without problem and no additional memory is needed.